# how to unstage a renamed file in git index?

Tags: git

I'm always using `git checkout <file>` to unstage uncommited changes, however I can't seem to do this when files were renamed.

git just can't pickup the file I want to unstaged, tried this with no luck:

```
git checkout <oldfilename>
```

and

```
git checkout <newfilename>
```

returns `error: pathspec '<file>' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `git reset -- newfilename` to unstage the renamed file.

If instead of unstaging you are looking to rename the file back, use `git mv newfilename oldfilename`.

Comment: Thanks.. seems like I need both.